# Android- Pixel color matcing estimate

Tags: android

I'm making an Android app in which a color is shown on the screen, and within 30 secs, player has to take a picture of something that includes the shown color before the time runs out. Points (up to 1000 per round!) are awarded based on how close the match is

I just want to know how to measure the closeness in color between the captured image and shown image and how to rate the closeness in the range [0:1000]

Is anyone familiar with such an approach? How would you do something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) to get L,a, and b of the two images. Then get delta of each L,a,and b. Then get the distance between 2 images with `distance=sqrt(deltaL^2+deltaA^2+deltaB^2)`. The greater the distance then the lower the point (0..1000). Use normalization for that. Just conver distance into range 0..1000. Hope This help you